# Изменение переменной-члена класса через константный метод по константной ссылке

Tags: c++

Начал изучать классы по C++. Как я понял из прочитанного материала по классам, что  константные методы нельзя менять переменные-члены классов, а в задаче как я понял требуется. Помогите решить.
Вот задача из учебника Праты:

```
class Move 
{ 
private: 
double x; 
double y; 
public: 
Move (double a = 0, double b = 0) ; // устанавливает х, у в a, b 
showmove const; // отображает текущие значения х, у 
Move add (const Move & m) const; 
// Эта функция добавляет х из m к х вызывающего объекта, 
// чтобы получить новое значение х, 
// Добавляет у из m к у вызывающего объекта, чтобы получить новое 
// значение у, присваивает инициализированному объекту значения х, у 
// и возвращает его 
reset (double a = 0, double b = 0) ; // сбрасывает х, у в a, b 
};
```

Comment: `Move add (const Move & m) const; `, тут нет никакой ссылки, вы возвращаете копию, т.е. новый объект. А это значит, что вы берете новый объект, и у него вызываете его конструктор с параметрами которые складываете, т.е. `return Move(m.x + x, m.y + y);`

Comment: Что за `showmove const;`? Думаю тут должно быть что-то вроде `void showmove() const;`...

Comment: showmove const; это опечатка в книге.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Move add (const Move & m) const;` , тут нет никакой ссылки, вы возвращаете копию, т.е. новый объект. А это значит, что вы берете новый объект, и у него вызываете его конструктор с параметрами которые складываете, т.е. `return Move(m.x + x, m.y + y);`

```
#include <iostream>

class move
{
private:
    double x, y;

public:
    move(double x = .0, double y = .0) : x(x), y(y)
    {
    }

    void show() const
    {
        std::cout << "x: " << x << ", y: " << y << std::endl;
    }

    move add(const move& m) const
    {
        return move(m.x + x, m.y + y);
    }

    void reset(double a = .0, double b = .0)
    {
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
};

int main() {
    move m(2.5, 2.5);
    move new_move = m.add(move(2.5, 2.5));
    new_move.show();
    return 0;
}
```

[Вывод:](https://ideone.com/zr1jkk)

> x: 5, y: 5

P.S. Если вас волнует переданный параметр `const Move & m`, то тут, да передается константная ссылка, которая не позволит вам изменить содержимое объекта, однако, это делается для того что бы можно было передать `r-value` ссылку как параметр.

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Я примерно так и думал что через конструктор должно складывается.

Comment: @Serj525 если ответ вам помог, поставьте галочку на нем, порадуете человека бонусной репутацией на сайте